# Can't figure out how to do XMLHttpRequest to google app engine

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-app-engine, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to do a simple POST from a javascript (google chrome extension) to my google app
I can see that the HTTP POST is indeed sent to the GAE server, but I can't figure how to transfer a simple text string, and use it in the google app.

The goal: send a string from the javascript with xmlhttpRequest, show this string on google-app webpage.

Here's the code of the javascript:

```
  function onRequest(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var url = request;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://myapp.appspot.com");
    xhr.send(url);
    // Return nothing to let the connection be cleaned up.
    sendResponse({});
  };
```

Here's how I deal with the post in the server side:

```
def post(self):
    url1 = str(self.request.get('url1'))
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write('<p>URL is: %s</p>' % url1)
```

When I look at the POST response I see

```
<p>URL is: </p>
```

where is the var url that was sent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it to work, in a different way. Instead of XMLHttpRequest, I used jquery:

```
    $.post("http://myapp.appspot.com", { url1: request});
```

and it worked :)

BTW, I also discovered that if you want the chrome extension's html to use jquery, you need to do

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script> your code here </script>
```

(I'm sure it's basic for you guys but fresh for me :)

Comment: I'm running into this same pattern of discovery (2012, now).  I can't find a good XMLHttpRequest way to do it, but there are a few $.ajax{stuff} solutions.  Could you post the resource you used for learning about the $.post(...) method?

Answer (score 0):

The content you include with `xhr.send()` will be in self.request.body, if it's not specified in CGI format.  For your simple test, you might also try `xhr.send("url1=" + request)`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. Did you mean maybe xhr.send("url=" + request)? (you wrote 'url1' not 'url')